# How to register decorators conditionally based on consumer lifestyle using Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a scenario where I have two classes, let's call them `SingletonWorker` and `ScopedWorker`, registered with Singleton and Scoped lifestyles respectively. Both depend on `IMetricSubmitter` in their constructor. The workers submit metrics as part of their logic using the `IMetricSubmitter`. There's a singleton implementation for `IMetricSubmitter` called `DefaultMetricSubmitter`, which I like to decorate with `EnrichMetricsDecorator` for the purpose of `ScopedWorker` dependency, such that `SingletonWorker` will end up with `DefaultMetricSubmitter` and `ScopedWorker` will end up with `EnrichMetricsDecorator` decorating `DefaultMetricSubmitter`. Is there a way to create such registrations using SimpleInjector today?

The object graphs should basically look like this:

```
var singleton = new SingletonWorker(
    new DefaultMetricSubmitter());

var scoped = new ScopedWorker(
    new EnrichMetricsDecorator(
        new DefaultMetricSubmitter()));
```

To me it looks like combining the `RegisterConditional`, which has a predicate that knows about the consumer, with `RegisterDecorator` which is the way to register decorators, but I don't know of any way to combine the two. Ideally I'd like to register the decorator with a condition that is based on whether there's an active scope when it's requested as a dependency for a consuming constructor, and in that case create the decorator instance for that active scope. For the purpose of debate, the scope can be assumed to be `LifetimeScope`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible using the `RegisterDecorator` methods. Instead, you will have to revert to using the `RegisterConditional` methods. Considering your given object graph, these registrations should look something like this:

```
container.Register<ScopedWorker>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<SingletonWorker>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

container.RegisterConditional<IMetricSubmitter, EnrichMetricsDecorator>(
    Lifestyle.Scoped,
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(ScopedWorker));

container.RegisterConditional<IMetricSubmitter, DefaultMetricSubmitter>(
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(EnrichMetricsDecorator));
```

This practice is described [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#applying-decorators-conditionally-based-on-consumer) in the documentation.

**UPDATE**

With your updated object graph (that includes an extra singleton decorator), the registration might look as follows:

```
// Useful helper method
static bool InjectedInto<TConsumer>(PredicateContext c) =>
    c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(TConsumer);

container.Register<ScopedWorker>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<SingletonWorker>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

container.RegisterConditional<IMetricSubmitter, DefaultMetricSubmitter>(
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    InjectedInto<CachingMetricSubmitterDecorator>);

container.RegisterConditional<IMetricSubmitter, CachingMetricSubmitterDecorator>(
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    c=> !InjectedInto<ScopedWorker>(c)&&!InjectedInto<CachingMetricSubmitterDecorator>(c));

container.RegisterConditional<IMetricSubmitter, EnrichMetricsDecorator>(
    Lifestyle.Scoped, 
    InjectedInto<ScopedWorker>);
```

Comment: According to the documentation this registration won't have the `EnrichMetricsDecorator` decorate the singleton `DefaultMetricsSubmitter`, am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it well. Looks exactly what I need, will check it out. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Steven, your suggestion worked but I have a bit more complicated object graph where it fails. Continuing the example above, the `DefaultMetricSubmitter` should be always decorated with singleton `CachingMetricSubmitterDecorator`, and the `CachingMetricSubmitterDecorator` should be decorated with `EnrichMetricsDecorator` based on the condition that the consumer has `Scoped` lifestyle. So the `SingletonWorker` should receive a `CachingMetricSubmitterDecorator` decorating a `DefaultMetricsSubmitter`.  How should I approach this?

Comment: @Eldar: There is no way of getting the lifestyle of the consuming component inside the predicate, and I would argue that making the decision based on the lifestyle is not a good idea at all. You might even want to reevaluate your strategy here. But nontheless, I updated my answer to show you how to make the registration with the extra decorator.

Comment: I dislike the situation I ended up with as well, but our monitoring framework demands that when I create my `MetricSubmitter` instance I make decisions about which metric dimensions should be included. Many of my objects are scoped to a context where the metric dimensions should be enriched with 3 dimensions available via an ambient context similar to WebApi's request context. I wanted to implement the enrichment using a decorator, and the best way I could find to apply the enrichment only in the correct context is by decorating only when consumed by scoped objects scoped to the right context.

Comment: @Eldar you can always make the registration using a lambda.